# how to get one column list in DBFlow

Tags: dbflow

I am using DBflow. I have tried many times to try and make a query as follows:

```
public class ScoreRepository {

    public List<Score> findAllScore() {
        return SQLite.select()
                .from(Score.class)
                .queryList();
    }

    public List<String> findScore01() {
        return SQLite.select()
                .from(Score.class)
                .queryList();
    }
}
```

In my case `findScore01()`, this method does not work. I want to make one column String List. I do not want to make an Object List.

Answer (score 0):

**queryList** will give you list of '`Score`' Class. To get custom data,

*e.g ( join of two tables, or in your case, just 1 column)*

you need to make a class that extends from `QueryModel`. then use

```
.queryCustomList(customclass.class);
```

That will give you

```
List< customclass > ls;
```

Check this answer for more details:

[Get custom Data from 2 tables](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/1085)

Answer (score 0):

You can use queryCustomList for getting a sub table from an existing table or joining two tables. Like Farhan mentioned above you can create a QueryModel class with your required fields and use it to retrieve the score, but it still be a list of your custom model query class, and not list of strings like you needed.

Only solution I can think of is looping your result list and generate a list of strings like :

```
List<Score> scoreList = SQLite.select(Score_Table.score01)
                .from(Score.class)
                .queryList();
List<String> score01List = new ArrayList<>();
foreach(Score score: scoreList) {
    score01List.add(score.getScore01());
}
```